# Devices with Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean) supported Bluetooth low energy (BLE)

Tags: android, bluetooth, galaxy, bluetooth-lowenergy

Which Android (with Jelly Bean, 4.2) devices support [Bluetooth low energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy) (BLE)? Does [Samsung Galaxy S III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III) support it?

(This question came up after reading the blog post *[Bluetooth 4.0 on Galaxy S3](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=157757)*.)

Comment: You can find which devices has supported BLE [in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873905/how-to-find-out-if-android-device-supports-bluetooth-low-energy/19134884#19134884)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that currently only the Motorola RAZR has BLE support (because Motorola provides their own BLE library to developers).  The S3 does not support BLE (drivers / API not available).

This [letter from the COOKOO watch project](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/cuckoo/cookootm-the-watch-for-the-connected-generation/posts/352332) describes Android's Bluetooth 4.0 disaster well.

Additionally, [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33371) has become the unofficial venting / complaining forum for developers. There are occasionally some useful updates there.

**Edit**

Bluetooth low energy is now officially supported in Android 4.3 (API 18).  Check the developer's guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html).

Answer (score 1):

No Android phone currently supports BLE. Some phones have the BLE chipset but since Android doesn't support BLE, the BLE hardware is basically unusable.

Comment: This has been changed since launch of SDK18 / Android 4.3

Comment: It's amazing that this system allows people to downvote answers and trash other people's reputation without having to explain why and requires no accountability. My answer was correct at the time it was written. If this has changed, the civilized way would be to add a comment with the change and not to downvote the answer.

Answer (score -1):

My Samsung Galaxy S2 works nicely with the Polar H7 bluetooth heartrate monitor, using MyTracks. Which, I assume, means that the SGS2 supports BTLE
No such luck with my Nexus4 though.

Comment: SGS2 doesn't support BLE

Comment: True, I actually didn't have the Polar H7, but another Polar model. Sorry for the confusion.