# Scan a 4.0 Bluetooth device it's not working

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Im doing an android app to pair a non-android device with bluetooth 4.0 LE, but my 4.0Bluetooth-android-phone doesnt discover the device anyway. I discover other devices like phones, or tablets.

The question is: Do i have to add some extra code if i want to work with bluetooth 4.0 devices?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you make your '4.0 device' discoverable with device settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth 4.0 (or BLE) is not supported in Android at the moment. It will be supported in Android 4.3 (API level 18). Among other places, you can read more about it [here](http://www.nordicsemi.com/kor/News/News-releases/Product-Related-News/Industry-giant-Google-sets-timeline-for-native-Bluetooth-low-energy-support-in-Android-this-summer) and [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/bluetooth-low-energy-support-coming-future-android-version). Several Android devices has already been certified with Bluetooth 4.0 support, but it won't work before the update is released.

That said, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118658/devices-with-android-4-2-jelly-bean-supported-bluetooth-low-energy-ble) some devices does support it, but they need custom BLE libraries that the companies have developed.