# How to find out if Android device supports Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

It seems Nexus 7 first generation doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy, at least when I follow exactly steps from tutorial

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

I do have app finish on following code:

```
 if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

Sure I checked, that Bluetooth enabled.

So the question is, how to find out for sure, if the device supports Bluetooth Low Energy standard?

UPDATE: I'm using android 4.3

Comment: abovesun, the first gen Nexus 7 does not support BLE, the second gen does (2013 version).

Comment: That code should be enough to ckeck it, as it's said here Nexus7 first generation does not support BLE

Answer (score 13):

Your code is really good,
But do you add the following code exactly?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

The important code is :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>
```

Because we need to make sure the application can run succesfully,

> However, if you want to make your app available to devices that don't support BLE, you should still include this element in your app's manifest, but set required="false"

That code works for me.

**EDIT:**
I found something good for you about [**which devices be compatible with BLE feature**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy)

Comment: I use Galaxy Tab - GT-P1010. What's wrong? I found something good for you about which device be compatible with BLE feature.[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy]

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to check for the 'feature':

```
PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
boolean hasBLE = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
```

I'm not really sure how seriously the manufacturers take this though - the only feature I've checked myself is FEATURE_TELEPHONY and different manufacturers handle it in different (and puzzling) ways, so your mileage may vary, but I do believe that this is the way you are intended to do it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I must be blind - I didn't see that.  It sounds like the N7 is reporting to you that it does not have BLE, and that is correct for the 2012 N7.

Comment: Tom, it seems yes, but I can't find prove in official n7 specification

Answer (score 0):

The Android Bluetooth architecture completely changed from Android 4.1 to 4.2.  Any device with Android Jelly Bean 4.2 or later can not support Bluetooth Low Energy because it's not available in the new Bluedroid stack. See:

http://events.linuxfoundation.org/images/stories/slides/abs2013_rymanowski.pdf

Comment: You're right about them adopting a new bluetooth stack in 4.2 (for nexus devices), but support for BLE in the API was added in 4.3, and some Nexus devices got driver support for BLE at the same time.

Comment: Tom right, I did use nexus 7 with android 4.3, but it not works, I suppose it not supported on hardware level

Comment: Correct - the original N7 does not have the hardware support for BLE.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly provided the code to check if a supports device has BLE. That check sees if there is the feature `android.hardware.bluetooth_le` which is usually stored in a file named `android.hardware.bluetooth_le.xml` at the location `/system/etc/permissions` which you can manually navigate to with a file manager in the Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the N7 2012 does have the hardware support for BLE but Google's rom does not support it. I have a N72012 with the purity Rom installed and can confirm that it can connect to BLE devices.