# How to know if the Bluetooth chip in an Android phone supports bluetooth dual mode (simultaneous BR/EDR and BLE)?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

How to know if the Bluetooth chip in an Android phone supports Bluetooth dual- mode (simultaneous BR/EDR and BLE transports)?

Is there a list of dual-mode capable phones? 
Is it possible to be checked programmatically (using Java) in runtime?

Comment: Any updates on this?—Android 8 Oreo first started to have “proper BLE support” as far as I found out searching the net. Related?

Answer (score 0):

Any phone that runs Bluetooth 4.0+ is capable of Bluetooth dual-mode.

To find it programmatically: 
[How to find out if Android device supports Bluetooth Low Energy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873905/how-to-find-out-if-android-device-supports-bluetooth-low-energy)

Comment: Yes, I already had this check in the manifest: <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" /> and the phone does connect BLE if there is not any other Bluetooth connection at the same time.  However if I do have a Classic Bluetooth connection, like A2DP on the phone, then BLE is not possible to connect. The phone in question is a Samsung Galaxy S3, with KitKat (v 4.4.4).

Comment: Actually also same problem with another phone: Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9506) with Lollipop (v 5.0.1)