# Is Bluetooth Version 4.2 Supported by Android API?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I understand that BLE is supported by Android after Android 4.3. However, there is no mention of the BLE version supported in the documentation. What BLE versions are supported by API Level 18 (Android 4.3)? What BLE versions are supported by API Level 21 (Lollipop)? The latest Bluetooth version is 4.2. I am interested in the security features in Bluetooth 4.2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out if Android device supports Bluetooth Low Energy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873905/how-to-find-out-if-android-device-supports-bluetooth-low-energy)

Comment: I am not asking if an Android phone supports BLE. I am asking if the Android API (API 23) supports Bluetooth 4.2 features.

Comment: Which of these 3 upgrades in BLE 4.2 do you think needs a change in the API? http://blog.csr.com/2014/12/bluetooth-4-2-is-here-but-what-does-it-mean/

Comment: I need to know if the API will take advantage of the security/privacy features available in Bluetooth 4.2. If it does, then I can advertise that my app is Bluetooth 4.2 compliance. If the API can only create apps to communicate at BLE 4.0, then any new Bluetooth devices will have to run in backward-compatibility mode with my app.

Comment: AndrewF: have you found out since which Android version BLE 4.2 is supported?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know the Bluetooth Version of each Android version.But when i do BQB for my product,I found something.
I found the Qualcomm KK supports Version 4.0,https://www.bluetooth.org/tpg/QLI_viewQDL.cfm?qid=21772
,the "design description" and "Spec name" can tell you something.you may change the "21772" to "21773" to check the L version and you'll find it supports 4.2.

Hope it can help you.