# Cannot read property 'bluetoothGattService' of undefined

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, nativescript, adafruit

I'm working on a Nativescript bluetooth app. I'm using the plugin: https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-bluetooth

I'm able to scan for nearby devices and discover the services. I'm trying to attach a service/characteristic of 'write' to a button on my app. My function keeps returning an error when I click the button. It doesn't seem to even return the error inside the function. I've checked if my UUIDs are correct. Here is the CLI log:

```
 Successfully transferred services-page.js.
Refreshing application...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.myBLERegister on device FA72A03
04236.
JS: ---- Lollipop+ scanCallback result: {"type":"scanResult","UUID":"3A:01:3A:6A
:30:C6","name":null,"RSSI":-82,"state":"disconnected","advertisement":"Hv8GAAEJI
AImj9KgkqUJogD8bF6YsY/ZcTe3c0IL9gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=","ma
nufacturerId":6,"manufacturerData":{}}
JS: ---- Lollipop+ scanCallback result: {"type":"scanResult","UUID":"EB:FA:DB:31
:1B:A7","name":"Adafruit Bluefruit LE","RSSI":-64,"state":"disconnected","advert
isement":"AgEGAgoAEQaeytwkDuWp4JPzo7UBAEBuFglBZGFmcnVpdCBCbHVlZnJ1aXQgTEUAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAA="}
JS: ---- Lollipop+ scanCallback result: {"type":"scanResult","UUID":"30:AA:13:7D
:1F:4C","name":null,"RSSI":-86,"state":"disconnected","advertisement":"Hv8GAAEJI
AK0AyV4bcITNKXNBmQPDloOKoOyCtp+sAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=","ma
nufacturerId":6,"manufacturerData":{}}
JS: !!&&&&***** Clicked item with index 1
JS: --- peri selected: EB:FA:DB:31:1B:A7
JS: Connecting to peripheral with UUID: EB:FA:DB:31:1B:A7
JS: ------- _MyGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange, status: 0, new state: 2
JS: ---- discovering services..
JS: ------- _MyGattCallback.onServicesDiscovered, status (0=success): 0
JS: ------- Peripheral connected: {"UUID":"EB:FA:DB:31:1B:A7","name":"Adafruit B
luefruit LE","state":"connected","services":[{"UUID":"1800","characteristics":[{
"UUID":"2a00","name":"2a00","properties":{"read":true,"write":true,"writeWithout
Response":false,"notify":false,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticated
SignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":false},"descriptors":[]},{"UUID":"2a01"
,"name":"2a01","properties":{"read":true,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":fa
lse,"notify":false,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites
":false,"extendedProperties":false},"descriptors":[]},{"UUID":"2a04","name":"2a0
4","properties":{"read":true,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify"
:false,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"ext
endedProperties":false},"descriptors":[]}]},{"UUID":"1801","characteristics":[{"
UUID":"2a05","name":"2a05","properties":{"read":false,"write":false,"writeWithou
tResponse":false,"notify":false,"indicate":true,"broadcast":false,"a...
JS: ---- ###### adding service: 1800
JS: ---- ###### adding service: 1801
JS: ---- ###### adding service: 00001530-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
JS: ---- ###### adding service: 180a
JS: ---- ###### adding service: 6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e
JS: Error in Bluetooth.writeWithoutResponse: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bl
uetoothGattService' of undefined
JS: Error in Bluetooth.writeWithoutResponse: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bl
uetoothGattService' of undefined
JS: Error in Bluetooth.writeWithoutResponse: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bl
uetoothGattService' of undefined
```

services.page.js

```
    function onWriteOpen() {
  bluetooth.writeWithoutResponse(
    {
      UUID: _peripheral.UUID,
      serviceUUID: '6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e', // read write service of BLE device
      characteristicUUID: '6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e', // transmit characteristic of BLE device service
      value: '0x4f',
      //awaitResponse: false // if false you will not get notified of errors (fire and forget) 
    }
   ).then(
    function(result) {
    console.log("Writing " + value + "on " + _peripheral.UUID);
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log("Failed to write " + value + "on "+ _peripheral.UUID + err);
    }
  );
}
```

xml file with button component

```
    <Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <StackLayout col="0" orientation="vertical">
    <StackLayout col="0" orientation="vertical" class="tab-content">
      <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <Label text="{{ name }}" class="details-label-title" />
        <Label text=" services" class="details-label-title details-label-title-postfix" />
      </StackLayout>
      <Label text="{{ UUID }}" class="details-services-uuid" />
      <!--<Label text="{{ state }}" />-->
      <Button text="disconnect" tap="onDisconnectTap" class="button button-positive" />
    </StackLayout>

    <ActivityIndicator busy="{{ isLoading }}"/>

    <StackLayout>
    <Button text="Open" tap="onWriteOpen" class="button button-positive" />
    </StackLayout>

    <GridLayout rows="*">
      <ListView items="{{ services }}" itemTap="onServiceTap" separatorColor="#90c3d4">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
          <StackLayout col="0" class="tab-content">
            <Label text="{{ name }}" />
            <Label text="{{ UUID }}" visibility="{{ name != UUID ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}" />
          </StackLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </GridLayout>

  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

UPDATE 10/16:
Testing on Pixel 1 with Android 9 OS.
The plugin AndroidManifest file in the bluetooth plugin already includes the suggested permission line.

The device is shown when I scan. Here are two screenshots of the app:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZctnJ.jpg

When I select the device I can then see the available services. I want to use the last one for my buttons. I have used the demo app to manually write a hex value to the device and it works. I'm just trying to attach the entire action to buttons.
Original demo app: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-bluetooth-demo

10/17/18:
Running the demo and manually selecting the write/read service and then the write characteristic sending a value I get these results.

```
JS: --- peri selected: EB:FA:DB:31:1B:A7
JS: Connecting to peripheral with UUID: EB:FA:DB:31:1B:A7
JS: ------- _MyGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange, status: 0, new state: 2
JS: ---- discovering services..
JS: ------- _MyGattCallback.onServicesDiscovered, status (0=success): 0
JS: ------- Peripheral connected: {"UUID":"EB:FA:DB:31:1B:A7","name":"ZoneFirst BLE","state":"connected","services":[{"UUID":"1800","characteristics":[{"UUID":"2a00","name":"2a00",
"properties":{"read":true,"write":true,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":false,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":false},
"descriptors":[]},{"UUID":"2a01","name":"2a01","properties":{"read":true,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":false,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticated
SignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":false},"descriptors":[]},{"UUID":"2a04","name":"2a04","properties":{"read":true,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":false,"
indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":false},"descriptors":[]}]},{"UUID":"1801","characteristics":[{"UUID":"2a05","name":"2a05","
properties":{"read":false,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":false,"indicate":true,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":false},
"descriptors":[{"UUID":"2902","value":null}]}]},{"UUID":"00001530-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123","characteristics":[{"UUID":"00001532-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123","name":"00001532-12
12-efde-1523-785feabcd123","properties":{"read":false,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":true,"notify":false,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,
"extendedProperties":false},"descriptors":[]},{"UUID":"00001531-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123","name":"00001531-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123","properties":{"read":false,"write":true,"
writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":true,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":false},"descriptors":[{"UUID":"2902","value":nul
l}]},{"UUID":"00001534-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123","name":"00001534-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123","properties":{"read":true,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":fals
e,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":false},"descriptors":[]}]},{"UUID":"180a","characteristics":[{"UUID":"2a29","name":"2a29
","properties":{"read":true,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":false,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":fals
e},"descriptors":[]},{"UUID":"2a24","name":"2a24","properties":{"read":true,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":false,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authentica
tedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":false},"descriptors":[]},{"UUID":"2a28","name":"2a28","properties":{"read":true,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":fals
e,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":false},"descriptors":[]},{"UUID":"2a26","name":"2a26","properties":{"read":true,"write":
false,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":false,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":false},"descriptors":[]},{"UUID":"2a27",
"name":"2a27","properties":{"read":true,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":false,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProp
erties":false},"descriptors":[]}]},{"UUID":"6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e","characteristics":[{"UUID":"6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e","name":"6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-
e50e24dcca9e","properties":{"read":false,"write":false,"writeWithoutResponse":false,"notify":true,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProp
erties":false},"descriptors":[{"UUID":"2901","value":null},{"UUID":"2902","value":null}]},{"UUID":"6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e","name":"6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9
e","properties":{"read":false,"write":true,"writeWithoutResponse":true,"notify":false,"indicate":false,"broadcast":false,"authenticatedSignedWrites":false,"extendedProperties":fals
e},"descriptors":[{"UUID":"2901","value":nul
JS: l}]}]}]}
JS: ---- ###### adding service: 1800
JS: ---- ###### adding service: 1801
JS: ---- ###### adding service: 00001530-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
JS: ---- ###### adding service: 180a
JS: ---- ###### adding service: 6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e
JS: --- service selected: 6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e
JS: ------- _MyGattCallback.onCharacteristicWrite
JS: android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic@75d8936
```

I can see the callback of the write in this case. But using a button returns the *TypeError: Cannot read property 'bluetoothGattService' of undefined*

Comment: Can you share a playground sample for this.

Comment: Try this link: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=D8i4FM&v=6

Comment: What is the device which you are trying to test and version.

Comment: Check if your devices has the following services true after getting connected to the device. properties: {
          read: true,
          write: true,
          writeWithoutResponse: true,
          notify: true
        }

Comment: Also check f your manifest has this line - <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/> From another android issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873905/how-to-find-out-if-android-device-supports-bluetooth-low-energy

Comment: Those permissions / features are added to manifest by the plugin itself. Did you try to scan and make sure the other device is visible?

Comment: Yes the device is visible and the manifest file in the plugin takes care of the permissions. Baskar I think you're on to something about the services being true after connecting. See my update above. The original demo app does show the service 6e400001 with the properties being true. But my app doesn't have it show up when connected. However, I do see the service being added and can see it on the app.

Comment: Forgot to mention, Testing on Pixel 1 with Android 9 OS. I think the bluetooth plugin was missing on the playground project when I first linked it.