# Can i read data from BT 4.0 Chip ( HM-10) with phone that support BT 2.0 and lower than jellybean

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I have phone that  running android version lower than jelly bean. And I want to read sensor data from HM-10 BLE Chip.

Can i do that with app inventor or native android code?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118658/devices-with-android-4-2-jelly-bean-supported-bluetooth-low-energy-ble